# Create nullable object based on nullable value

Tags: dart, null, dart-null-safety

i have to create a domain class object which has a nullable attribute. This Creating is in an extansion of a primitive class.

For example: Domainclass

```
Meeting({required String id, required Datetime date, Example? example})
```

behind Example is an class like so: Example(String value)

MeetingPrimitive.dart:

```
extension MeetingPrimitiveX on Meeting {

Meeting toDomain() {
  return Meeting(
    id: id,
    date: date,
    example: example == null ? null : Example(example)
}

}
```

My question is, how can i simplify this:

```
example == null ? null : Example(example)
'''


thanks in advance
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally can't.
You can *change* it in various ways, but nothing is more direct than what you have here.

One variant would be:

```dart
extension DoWith<T> on T {
  R doWith<R>(R Function(T) action) => action(this);
}
```

With that, you can write:

```dart
 example?.doWith(Example.new)
```

to conditionally call the `Example.new` constructor (tear-off of the unnamed constructor) if `example` is non-`null`.

Slightly shorter, requires a helper function, and ... isn't actually more readable IMO.